# Removing elements from an aml using ElementTree in python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, elementtree

So I have an xml

```
<a>
    <b><\b>
    <b><\b>
</a>
```

and I run

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree
et = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse('abc.xml')
root = et.getroot()
for x in root:
    root.remove(x)        
print(xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring(root))
```

expecting `<a></a>` as output but I get this `<a><b /></a>`

What am I misunderstanding here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
for x in root:
```

to

```
for x in root.findall('*'):
```

Comment: This works but what is wrong in the code in the question?

Comment: @gst1502 - Not really sure; apparently this library has a lot of other problems. I personally prefer to use lxml, whenever possible.